# Qt Slot function not invoked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I cannot for the live of me figure out why my function isn't called correctly after connecting it.

.h file

```
class NewCustomer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    QWidget* newCustomer = new QWidget;
    QDialogButtonBox* buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

    NewCustomer(QObject *parent);
    ~NewCustomer();

    private slots:
    void aAccepted();
};
```

.cpp file

```
void thisfunctionworksthough() {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
    msgBox.exec();
}

NewCustomer::NewCustomer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(this->buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, &NewCustomer::aAccepted);
    connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, thisfunctionworksthough);
    newCustomer->setMinimumSize(700, 600);
    newCustomer->show();
}

void NewCustomer::aAccepted() {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

The free function works but the one inside the class defined as slot doesn't. Why?

Comment: One is mapped to the Ok button (accepted) and the other one to the Cancel button (rejected). When I press Ok nothing happens, when I press Cancel I get the message.

Comment: Does this code compile ?

Comment: @H.G Yes, although I removed the includes and some other widgets to make a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very stupid of me, but apparently I created the class instance by value so it got deleted when the scope ended. I made sure that it won't get freed from memory so quickly and now it works like a charm.